# PostgreSQL Custom user type (not java primitive types) to hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql

I want to know how to map this kind of scenario in the hibernate. I have found many answers in the web. but those are not give any standard approach. i wan to know the correct way of doing this in the hibernate ?

```
CREATE TYPE custom_type AS (
id int,
amount numeric
); 

CREATE TABLE journal_entry (
id serial not null unique,
date_time date not null,
description text, 
custom_items custom_type[]
);
```

I'm pretty new to PostgreSQL and hibernate please help me ?

Comment: Does this forum post answer your question: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=981858

Comment: thankx man i think it has a pretty good answer.